# Outline Server was installed correctly, but are not able to connect to it

Tags: ubuntu, vpn, firewall, outline, droplet

I'm trying to config `Outline VPN` and
I bought a `Droplet` from `Digitalocean` with **`Ubuntu 22`**.

So, my server generated URI string correctly:

```
CONGRATULATIONS! Your Outline server is up and running.

To manage your Outline server, please copy the following line (including curly
brackets) into Step 2 of the Outline Manager interface:

{"apiUrl":"https://***.***.***.***:41591/nBGhsdKbtPJL35f8LfA","certSha256":"ABCSDED8BF654ABDD9FD46DB936D122FDDE7B4815SDDA2757B5133C1A74E7"}
```

in addition, script says:

```
Make sure to open the following ports on your firewall, router or cloud provider:
- Management port 41591, for TCP
- Access key port 28592, for TCP and UDP
```

This is my `iptables -L` result:

```
root@ubuntu-s-1gb-nyc1-01:/etc/init.d# iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:41591
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:41591
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:28592
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:28592
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpts:1024:65535
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpts:1024:65535

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain DOCKER (0 references)
```

And `ufw`:

```
root@ubuntu-s-1gb-nyc1-01:/etc/init.d# ufw status
Status: inactive
```

As I have a `digitalocean Droplet`, this is my firewall config on digital ocean panel:

[image]

[image]

And finally, when I check my pot and IP, I give this result:

[image]

This is my outline manager report:

[image]

> Does anyone know what is wrong with my configuration?

Answer (score 1):

Technically you did everything all right. the Problem is server manager app cannot connect your server because of internet censorship. This issue causes you stuck in key generation step. You need to apply another working VPN service during server management, the manager app works like a charm afterwards!